# LGBM binary classification probabilities do not match up to simulated expectations

Tags: python, cross-validation, loss-functions, boosting

I have a dataset with roughly 100 predictor variables and 20K examples that have binary classifications. My goal is to minimize binary cross-entropy loss, and given the nature of the data, I decided to use LGBM.

I utilize 5-Fold CV, and for each test fold, I find p(success). I then calculate the binary cross-entropy loss (L1) utilizing p(success) and the ground truth values. Then for each p(success), I ignore what actually happened and instead simulate values based on those probabilities, and calculate the binary cross-entropy loss (L2) utilizing p(success) and the simulated values.

I've observed after running LGBM many times utilizing different shuffling groups that L1 < L2, and I can't wrap my head around why this bias is happening. If the values that the model spits out are correct probabilities, then I'd expect that the actual outcomes wouldn't matter and that if we simulated outcomes utilizing those same probabilities that we would get similar results.

```
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from pybaseball import statcast_pitcher # pip install pybaseball

def calculate_binary_logloss(predictions, actual):
    return -(actual * np.log(predictions) + (1-actual)*np.log(1-predictions)).mean()

def create_simulated_predictions(probabilities):
    """Create a vectorized version of np.random.choice with different probabilities"""

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474436/how-to-apply-numpy-random-choice-to-a-matrix-of-probability-values-vectorized-s
    p = np.vstack((1-probabilities, probabilities)).T.cumsum(axis=1)
    u = np.random.rand(probabilities.shape[0], 1)
    simulated_values = (u < p).argmax(axis=1)
    return simulated_values

def run_kfold(df):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
    l1_list = []
    l2_list = []

    for train_indx, test_indx in kf.split(df):
       training_df = df.iloc[train_indx]
       testing_df = df.iloc[test_indx]
       X_train, X_test = training_df.drop(columns=['Outcome']), testing_df.drop(columns=['Outcome'])
       Y_train, Y_test = training_df['Outcome'], testing_df['Outcome']

       clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='binary', metric='binary_logloss', feature_fraction=0.4, max_depth=10)
       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

       test_predictions = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
       simulated_y_values = create_simulated_predictions(test_predictions)

       L1 = calculate_binary_logloss(test_predictions, Y_test)
       L2 = calculate_binary_logloss(test_predictions, simulated_y_values)

       l1_list.append(L1)
       l2_list.append(L2)

    return l1_list, l2_list

def main():
    # will take around 20 seconds
    data = statcast_pitcher('2016-01-01', '2019-12-01', player_id=434378)

    df = data[data['type'] != 'X']
    df['Outcome'] = df['type'] == 'S'
    df = df[['release_speed', 'release_pos_x', 'release_pos_z', 'balls', 'strikes', 'pfx_x', 'pfx_z', 'plate_x', 
     'plate_z', 'vx0', 'vy0', 'vz0', 'ax', 'ay', 'az', 'sz_top', 'sz_bot', 'effective_speed', 
     'release_spin_rate', 'release_extension', 'Outcome']]
    df = df.dropna(axis=0)

    # run the experiment several times
    l1_test = []
    l2_test = []
    for _ in range(10):
        l1, l2 = run_kfold(df)
        print(np.array(l1).mean(), np.array(l2).mean())  # L1 is always lower than L2
        l1_test.append(l1)
        l2_test.append(l2)
    print (np.array(l1_test).mean(), np.array(l2_test).mean())
    # 0.3000, 0.3218
```

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example? Not just the methods you created.

Comment: @usεr11852 I've updated the question to add an example